# $\nabla (\vec{x}^T A \vec{x})$ where $\vec{x}\in R^n, A \in R^{n \times n}$

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, vectors

I know that $\nabla (\vec{x}^T A \vec{x})$ where $\vec{x}\in R^n, A \in R^{n \times n}$ equals $A\vec{x}+A^T\vec{x}$. However, I don't understand how one gets to this result.

So far I was able to do the following calculations:
$
\vec{x}^T A \vec{x} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i \sum_{j=1}^{n} x_j a_{j,i} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i( \sum_{j=1, j\neq i}^{n} (x_j a_{j,i}) + x_i a_{i,i})
$

Then I could take the partial derivative with respect to $x_i$:
$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1, j\neq i}^{n} (x_j a_{j,i}) + 2 x_i a_{i,i}
$

My question is, how the partial derivative can be transformed in vector form $A\vec{x}+A^T\vec{x}$

Comment: I suppose I wrote a detailed answer below, but there are 3 issues, (1) you've used $i$ both as the partial derivative but also as a free summation variable in your last expression, (2) you've only differentiated for the "outside" $x_i$ but note that your inside $x_j$ can equal $x_i$ too (which is why we should name these indices something else, and (3) you need to piece it back together into a vector by the end so you want to convert $ \sum a_{j,i} x_j$ into a vector component somehow (and you'll see how we did below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way. You can think of the partial with respect to $x_1$ as the difference quotient with $(x+te_1)^T A (x+te_1)$ i.e. you want $$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{t}[(x+te_1)^T A (x+te_1) - x^TAx]$$
$$ = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{t} [x^TAx + tx^TAe_1 + te_1^TAx+t^2e_1^Te_1-x^TAx]$$
$$ = \lim_{t\to 0} [x^TAe_1 + e_1^TAx + t] $$
$$= x^TAe_1 + e_1^TAx$$

Great, now let's figure out what's going on here. We want $x$ on the right, so let's use that transposes reverse the order of multiplication, and also noting that these expressions are numbers (so are equal to their own transpose) to write this as
$$(x^TAe_1)^T + e_1^TAx = e_1^T A^Tx + e_1^TAx$$

Great, how does this help? $e_1^TAx$ is just the 1st entry of $Ax$. So really we have $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1} x^TAx = (A^Tx)_1 + (Ax)_1$
Repeated for any index, we get  $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} x^TAx = (A^Tx)_i + (Ax)_i$, or simply, $\nabla x^TAx = (Ax + A^Tx)$

**Additional Info / Alternative Method**

Now, if you really wanted to spell it all out and take partial derivatives, we can do that too, we just need to keep track of indices well. Let's see. Note that $x^TAx = x^T(Ax) = x \cdot (Ax) = \sum_i x_i (Ax)_i$ and we have $(Ax)_i = \sum_j A_{ij} x_j$ so really we have $x^TAx = \sum_i \sum_j A_{ij} x_i x_j$. (Note, why was I able to move the $x_i$ inside? And also note this is the same as your first expression!)

We have too many indices floating around so let's rewrite this as $x^TAx = \sum_u \sum_v A_{uv}x_u x_v$. Now, we want the partial with respect to $i$. The only situations in which this partial is non-zero is if $u$ or $v$ equals $i$. The terms where $u$ equals $i$ are $\sum_v A_{iv} x_i x_v = x_i (\sum_v A_{iv} x_v) = x_i (Ax)_i$. Where the terms $v$ equals $i$, we have $\sum_u A_{ui} x_u x_i = x_i (\sum_u A_{ui} x_u)$. The last term doesn't simplify, and we have to use the same transpose of a number is itself trick, so it's the same as $x_i (\sum_u A^T_{iu} x_u) = x_i (A^Tx)_i$.
Great, so the term is $x_i( (Ax)_i + (A^Tx)_i)$ so the partial is just $(Ax)_i + (A^Tx)_i$, same as above!
Interesting note: Why did I not have to consider the case where $u=v=i$ and remove those? Are we not double counting? No we are not! The $u=v=i$ terms require the product rule on them since we have $A_{ii}x_ix_i$ for them, and although we didn't explicitly account for this, it effectively gets split evenly between the two cases - a little serendipitous.